# Unable to access API from React and Node through proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blockchain, cryptocurrency

am having a problem with React and Node that I am unable to debug. I have an API connection to coinmarketcap on my node server, which returns a list of coins and individual coins. I am getting the correct data returned for all the coins endpoint and the individual coin endpoint on postman but I am only getting all the coins on react, while the single coins return a 404 error.[Link to screenshot for API return of single coin on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zii54.png)

Here is my server side code for returning a single coin:

```js
module.exports = app => {

  app.get("/api/coin/:id", async(req, res) => {
    const symbolID = req.params.id;
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      uri: "https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info",
      qs: {
        symbol: symbolID.toUpperCase()
      },
      headers: {
        "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": keys.testCoinAPI
      },
      json: true,
      gzip: true
    };

    try {
      await rp(requestOptions).then(response => {
        res.send(response.data);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res.send("Sorry the currency you are looking for is not available");
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

};
```

Here is my React code to consume the API

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class ViewCoin extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      match: {
        params
      }
    } = this.props;

    axios.get(`/api/coin/${params.symbol}`).then(({
      data: coin
    }) => {
      console.log(coin);
      this.setState({
        coin
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <h1 > This is the view coin component < /h1>;
  }
}

export default ViewCoin;
```

Here is my renderCoins function to get the data into a table. With a link to individual ones.

```js
  renderCoins() {
    return this.props.coins.map(coin => {
      return (
        <tr key={coin.id}>
          <td>
            <Link to={`/coin/view/${coin.symbol}`}>{coin.name}</Link>
          </td>
          <td>{coin.symbol}</td>
          <td>${coin.quote.USD.price}</td>
          <td>${coin.quote.USD.market_cap}</td>
          <td>{coin.circulating_supply}</td>
          <td>${coin.quote.USD.volume_24h}</td>
          <td>{coin.quote.USD.percent_change_24h}%</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
```

I am also using a proxy to route the backend and frontend ports:

```js
 app.use(proxy("/api/*", { target: "http://localhost:5000" }));
```

I am able to access endpoints such as /api/coin/btc with no problem using the browser and postman. However, when using React I am getting a 404 error:
GET http://localhost:3000/api/coin/BTC 404 (Not Found)

Am I missing something with the proxy or did I mess up my route? Any help is appreciated, not sure what am missing/not seeing.

Comment: You have target as `"http://localhost:5000"` using port 5000, but the error you point out is trying to use 3000, `http://localhost:3000/api/coin/BTC` is that just an error in writing the question?

Comment: http://localhost:5000 is pointing to the port for the server. http://localhost:3000 is the react app. The proxy allows you to access routes on the 5000 port from the http://localhost:3000 on the frontend. It's not a typo, it's designed that way and it works for all my other APIs in the application. This particular error is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem. It was a problem with the proxy:

I had to include:  app.use(proxy("/api/**", { target: "http://localhost:5000" }));
in my proxy definition.